# BigQuery is not running my JOIN IN code, returning error `Unrecognized name: employees at [10:3]`

Tags: sql, error-handling, google-bigquery, syntax, inner-join

I am following the Google data analytics course and following the course guide.

I get the error

```
Unrecognized name: employees at [10:3]
```

My code:

```
SELECT 
    employees.name AS employee_name,
    employees_role AS employee_role,
    departments.name AS department_name,
FROM `western-will-410400.Employee_data`
INNER JOIN Employee_data.Departments
ON employees.department_id = deparments.department.id
```

Comment: Alias your tables and also likely need to repeat the database.... `select e.name, e.role, d.name as dept_name from western-will-410400.employee_data e join western-will-410400.departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id`.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: (Clearly) Your error(s) & goal will be faqs. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can not shorten the table names this way you need to alias them

```
SELECT 
  employees.name AS employee_name,
  employees_role AS employee_role,
  departments.name AS department_name,

 FROM `western-will-410400.Employee_data` as employees
 
 INNER JOIN
  Employee_data.Departments as deparments ON 
  employees.department_id = deparments.department.id
```